# SSIS Regex Component script

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I have a column with following data

```
NStreetNames
1245 Thfs Ext. drive.
2454 saaa Ext. Drive.
```

I want the output to be in 3 different columns such as

```
One    Two        Three

1245  THfs Ext.   Drive

2454  Saa Ext.    drive

 public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        /*
          Add your code here
        */
        string Val = Row.NStreetNames.ToString();
        Match match = Regex.Match(Val, @"^(?<One>\w+) (?<Two>\w+)(?: (?<Three>\w+))?$");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string o = match.Groups["One"].Value;
            string t = match.Groups["Three"].Value;
            string th = null;
            if (match.Groups["Two"].Success)
            {
                th = match.Groups["Two"].Value;
            }

            Row.StreetNumber = o;
            Row.Street = t;
            Row.Address = th;
        }
        else
            Row.StreetNumber = Row.NStreetNames.ToString();
    }
```

This code is just redirecting my all data into three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the the second and third column always end with a period `.` then you can extract all the information using the following:

```
^(?<One>\d+)\s(?<Two>[\w\s]+\.)\s(?<Three>\w+)\.$
```